# Can you have an Express API and use React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, routes

I know this seems obvious but I am trying to use URL params on my front end, AND have an API in the back end to grab data. I can get either one working and I am pretty sure this has to do with my app.js configuration

App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var customsiteRouter = require('./routes/customsite');
var app = express();


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

if(process.env.PORT){
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
});
}
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors()) // Use this after the variable declaration
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/customsite', customsiteRouter);

//DB Setup
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
let MongoDB = process.env.DB
mongoose.connect(MongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false})
.then(()=>{console.log('CONNECTED!!!!!!!!!!!!:)')});
var DB = mongoose.connection;



module.exports = app;
```

Here is my routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});


router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(`${req.params.id}`);
  console.log(req.params.id)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is where it gets messy.. I am using CRA in a client folder

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import Website from "./Components/Website";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import BasicTabs from "./Components/BasicTabs";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "100%",
    },
  },
}));

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <div className="App">
            <BasicTabs />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/website">
          <Website></Website>
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/custom/:id">
          <Website />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Question

I can use the URL [www.mywebsite.com/custom/test](http://www.mywebsite.com/custom/test)

And the website component renders with that ID

I also need to be able to run [www.mywebsite.com/users](http://www.mywebsite.com/users) And have that shoot off to the back end and call that API GET request

Is it possible to do both? Is my Express App.js set up incorrectly to handle both?

This is all on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

I think it is preferable to use https://www.postman.com/ to run the tests TWF, It's easy to install and to use and in generally, yes, you can have both of them. Didn't see any erros with your code